# NodeJS read emails pop3

Tags: node.js, pop3

I'm new to NodeJS and I did some googling but can't seem to find a free open source library to read emails from a POP3 server. Basically I want to do the following:

1. Read emails and their attachments
2. Read only unread emails

Comment: So you searched [the NPM site](https://www.npmjs.com) and...?

Comment: Yeah.  Only one I found that was good was this one. https://www.npmjs.com/~chilkat.  This one requires a license though.

Comment: In certain spaces you'll trip over the "Chilkat" stuff all the time, that developer is tenacious and I'm not even sure their code is any good. It's shipped as DLLs or obfuscated, which is really a deal-breaker for most applications. Try any of the other libraries first. Keep in mind POP3 is an antiquated protocol, virtually every provider has switched to IMAP, so support is limited.

Comment: Yeah.  POP3 is not good when trying to get unread emails.  Since they have no knowledge of read or unread emails. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Precisely. As far as I know you need to keep read/unread status information locally. POP3 is really bad at scaling to larger inboxes, at some point it pretty much melts down. IMAP has a proper sync system and understands red/flagging, etc.

Comment: So I implemented this in C# and the library I used tells me to push up an array of UID's of each email that is already on my system to get the unread ones.  To me that sounds so wrong but at the end of the day I guess how else would you do this.

Comment: If you're stuck with POP3 that's how it works. Ugly, inefficient, brutally bandwidth intensive. That's why the protocol is all but dead.

Comment: Thanks for validating for me that this is how pop3 works.  I was unsure if what I was doing right. I guess that is just how it is.   I think this library for nodejs might work for me.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/yapople

Comment: You can always read the [RFC from 1988](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1081) where the protocol is described. If you get this working you could self-answer with a useful snippet that could help others in the same jam.

Comment: Yes, Pop3 best works in a download-and-delete system, which is not how most people use email anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want mailpop3. It took me a while to find this answer myself.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailpop3